# Remove the first word of a string in lua

Tags: lua

What I'm looking for is something like the following, but it only applies to the first find it gets.

```
str:gsub("1", "")
```

I'd like it to only delete the first 1 it finds OR just the first word of the string.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
local str = "234243 232564 se42"
local str, i = str:gsub("1", "",1)  
print (str,i)
str  = (i>0) and str or str:gsub("^.-%s", "",1) 
print (str)
```

only when there are spaces in the string (more than one word).